# Descriptive variable name for NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a class called `Item` that's an NSManagedObject. `Item`s are created from NSDictionary objects. These NSDictionary objects exist in an NSArray that functions as the data model for its table view controller. The NSDictionary object has some functionality that would warrant wrapping it in a class (that is, I'd create a new class that has an NSDictionary instance var):

1. `save` gets called on it, at which point a download process starts
2. When `connectionDidFinishLoading`, I create and save an instance of `Item` from that NSDictionary data so that that `Item` instance persists.

I was thinking of `ItemRawData` or `ItemDictionary`, but they don't seem to really work (i.e. I don't like them).

The Items start out as JSON. Only when the user adds the item to his account/cart do we want the item to persist by creating an instance of `Item` and saving the context.

What is a descriptive name for this class that holds the "raw" data, does the downloading, and creates the `Item` object? Is there a common prefix or suffix that Objective-C or iOS dictates?

EDIT: Someone thinks this question should be closed. I'm not so much asking for your personal opinion on how to name this class as I am wondering whether there exists an Objective-C or iOS naming convention for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: When you say wrap NSDictionary in a class, do you mean you intend to subclass it? This is generally discouraged although not forbidden.

Comment: Yeah mpo is that an NSObject with an NSDictionary would be a better approach than just a subclassed NSDictionary. A category on NSDictionary might be another option to add save/download support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the position of this object in a clear-defined MVC paradigm (it sounds like the class may be mixing persisting data (models) with controlling (eg, performing downloading). But I leave the architecture to you as I don't know the full extent of your project.

A common design pattern or idiom is that of a "manager". This might be an appropriate candidate, with a name such as MYItemManager (with your own prefix, of course).

Comment: Ah, very interesting. Does it still make sense for TableViewController to have an array of `ItemManager`s? I will add that detail to my question.

Comment: If you look at the Manager design pattern, it's often a singleton - but in this case, we're not explicitly modeling the design pattern, just using the name, which I think is appropriate and certainly works as you're describing it here.

Comment: You might consider creating a shared ItemManager, and using it with items, so, for example, as you are iterating your model array, you pass each object to the manager, eg: [[MYItemManager sharedManager] itemForDictionary:dictionary]. Your manager could then perform (or queue) the loading and create the persistent item when necessary.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds quite complicated. The ItemManager would need to hold the NSDictionary data that it's currently downloading, but if the user attempts to download an Item while another is downloading, the previous item's data will get clobbered. A queuing mechanism sounds too complicated for what I'm trying to do... This is probably why I didn't intend for ItemManager to be a singleton... ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't your table's data source simply an array of your Item NSManagedObjects? Where are these dictionaries originating to begin with?

Comment: The items start out as NSDictionary objects because they are pulled in from a server as JSON data. When the user presses a button to add the item to his cart, we create the NSManagedObject so that it persists in the app.